# How can I solve this limit with a definite integral inside?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

This is the problem:

$$ \lim_{m \to 0}\left(\frac1m \int_{\sqrt\frac\pi 2}^{\sqrt\frac\pi 2+m}\sin(x^2)\,dx\right) $$

I don't have an idea how to solve it. I was thinking maybe it's an indeterminate form $ \infty \cdot 0$ and we can do something with l'hopital's rule. But I don't know what to do with the integral. What is the trick here?

Comment: Maybe it helps to define $F(m)= \int_{\sqrt\frac\pi 2}^{\sqrt\frac\pi 2+m}(sinx^2dx)$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)?

Comment: One does not need the general Lebesgue differentiation theorem since the integrand is smooth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that we have both

$$\lim_{m\to0} m=0\;\;\;\text{ and}\;\;\;\lim_{m\to0}\int_{\sqrt\frac \pi2}^{\sqrt\frac \pi2+m}\sin x^2\,dx=0$$

so by L'Hospital's rule, with $\;F(x)\;$ being a primitive function of $\;\sin x^2\;$ :

$$\lim_{m\to0}\frac{\int_{\sqrt\frac \pi2}^{\sqrt\frac \pi2+m}\sin x^2\,dx}m=\lim_{m\to0}\left[F\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}+m\right)-F\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}\right)\right]'=$$

$$=\lim_{m\to0}F'\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}+m\right)=\lim_{m\to0}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}+m\right)^2=\sin\frac\pi2=1$$

In the above, the derivative is with respect to $\;m\;$ , of course.

Comment: Can you please explain why $$ \lim_{m\to0}\left[F\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}+m\right)-F\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}\right)\right]'=\lim_{m\to0}F'\left(\sqrt{\frac \pi2}+m\right) $$ ?

Comment: The derivative **with respect to** $\;m\;$ on the left side equals the derivative in the right side. Observe that the second therm on the left side is a constant number and thus its derivative equals zero

Answer (score 4):

The result follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus. The limit is equal to
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{x}\sin(y^2)\,dy\bigg|_{x=a}=\sin(a^2)\tag{1}
$$

---

If you use l'Hopital,
then the limit is equal to
$$
\lim_{m\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{d}{dm}\int_a^{a+m}\sin(x^2)dx}{1}
$$
and you end up with the same result in (1).

Comment: FTC is the right approach. L'Hospital's is pretty roundabout here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh There is no "right" or "wrong" approach here. There is only correcto or incorrect, and in this case both FTC and L'Hospital are *correct*. Besides this, the very first line *is* in fact the definition of derivative at $\;\sqrt\frac\pi2\;$, and L'Hospital goes perfectly well with this. Now, if the requirements were not to use L'H then I'd agree.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I did not mean to say that L'Hospital's is incorrect, but rather more work. The result is immediate by FTC. But with L'Hospital's you first apply FTC to find derivatives and then take limit. Also I had given an upvote already as I agreed with the overall answer. I think we are on same page here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You say "the result is immediate by FTC"...but this is not completely accurate: **first** you must understand and deduce that the wanted limit is the definition of the derivative of the given integral at $\;\sqrt\frac\pi2\;$, otherwise you get nothing.. So there is also more work here than merely using FTC...

Comment: @DonAntonio: FTC says that if $F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ then $F'(x) =f(x) $ at points of continuity of $f$. Now by definition of derivative this means that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_c^{c+h}f(t)\,dt=f(c)$. So I would consider it an immediate consequence of FTC.

Answer (score 1):

*Another way to do it.*

Let $x=t+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$ to make
$$\int_{\sqrt\frac\pi 2}^{\sqrt\frac\pi 2+m}\sin(x^2)\,dx=\int_0^m \cos \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t+t^2\right)\,dt$$ Now, By Taylor and binomial expansion
$$\cos \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t+t^2\right)=1-\pi  t^2-\sqrt{2 \pi } t^3+O\left(t^4\right)$$
$$\int \cos \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t+t^2\right)\,dt=t-\frac{\pi  t^3}{3}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} t^4+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$\int_0^m \cos \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t+t^2\right)\,dt\sim m-\frac{\pi  m^3}{3}+O\left(m^4\right)$$
$$\frac 1m\int_0^m \cos \left(\sqrt{2 \pi } t+t^2\right)\,dt\sim 1-\frac{\pi  m^2}{3}+O\left(m^3\right)$$

Just for the fun, computing the exact value of the integral for $m=0.1$ (far away from $0$), the expression would be $0.9889$ while the approximation gives $1-\frac{\pi }{300}=0.9895$.